# Add two object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do something like this

```
    @qtn = []
    @questions.each do |q|
      @mc = q.answers
      @qtn << q + @mc
    end
```

but I get this error, `undefined method +`. I have two model Answer  and Question and they have one to many relationship. How can I make this work?

```
Edit:
```

Question.rb
has_many: answers

Answer.rb
belongs_to: question

I want output something like below to send it as json

```
@qtn = [
            {
                id: "",
                question_details: "",
                created_at: "",
                updated_at: "",
                [
                    {
                        id: "",
                        answer_details: "",
                        create_at: "",
                        updated_at: ""
                    },
                    {
                        id: "",
                        answer_details: "",
                        create_at: "",
                        updated_at: ""
                    }
                ]
            }



        ]
```

I am not sure if this this possible in rails but I think something like this is possible and hope you get my point what I am trying to do here.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish?  This may be easier to express with a query as opposed to you concatenating ActiveRecord entries together.  Also, how is the relationship defined?

Comment: Updated my question, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: So you're asking for all of the answers attached to an question then?

Comment: well yes, each question can have multiple answer and for each question I want those answers attached to it

Comment: I think the `answers` need to be in a key like this - `answers: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`? Otherwise `@qtn` wouldn't be a valid array of hashes.

Comment: yes, it should work. Could you please show me in the answer. I have been trying to to it but its not working

Comment: @user1670773 I know it's horrible to say, but you should really study Ruby before approaching Rails, this is not a Rails issue, you can handle this with array sum (which has a syntax similar to the one you proposed) or possibly with a single query, but it's not completely clear what are you trying to achieve in your code

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL - You should really study rails before suggesting a plain ruby approach which would be really slow and clunky. :). Array.sum is also an ActiveSupport method - its not even in the ruby core.

Comment: And I think you are thinking about array.map or select. Sum returns the sum of an array `[1,2,3].sum == 6`.

Comment: @max I'm quite experienced in Rails. Not only that, but I explicitly mention in my comment that it should be done with a single query for performance reasons, if possible (although it's still not clear by the context, the question isn't clear for me). Last but not least, `Array.sum` doesn't have to deal with anything in this case. He is asking for Array union which **is** default Ruby (yes, Ruby arrays supports all numeric operations). I highly doubt _summing an answer_ is possible, so before complaining please read correctly people comments. (Funny, you point to what I said in your answer)

Comment: "you can handle this with array sum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load the questions together with answers from the database:

```
@question = Question.eager_load(:answers).all
```

Then you can pass the `includes` option when serializing the questions as JSON:

```
@questions.to_json(include: :answers)
```

Sample JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "How much wood could a woodchuck chuck?",
    "created_at": "2015-07-11T20:47:24.241Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-07-11T20:47:24.241Z",
    "answers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "A lot",
        "question_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2015-07-11T20:47:41.096Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-07-11T20:47:41.096Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Adding two objects usually does not make much sense. Adding simple objects like numbers or strings or arrays together is one thing but what is expected result of adding two Apple objects or a Apple and a Pear?

In ruby adding `Apple.new + Apple.new` does not give you an array of apples. `[] + Apple.new` does not work either since it will attempt to coerce Apple into an array.

If you had to do the above without Rails serialization it would look something like:

```
@qtn = @questions.map do |q|
  q.to_hash.merge(answers: q.answers.map(&:to_hash))
end
```

Comment: Thanks! first part was the answer I was looking for. But for the second part without serialization I get this error undefined method `to_hash'

Comment: Thats is expected since rails the rails to hash function is called `serializable_hash` which would have made the example kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to turn it into JSON, then use the [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) method provided in ActiveRecord.

For your instance, since we want all questions, all we really have to do is this:

```
Questions.all.to_json
```

You can add an options hash to include (or exclude) certain fields or nested properties of it, as well.

Comment: I have another object q.answers which need to be attached to each questions also